# Combine 2 MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from `login_log` where from_unixtime(`date`) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

and the same one with 1 diff. it's not **1 WEEK** , but **1 MONTH** 
how can I combine those two and assign them to aliases?

Comment: You want them as two columns rather than two rows?

Comment: Currently I am just calling 2nd query , 2nd result with 'INTERVAL 1 MONTH', but simply yeah 2 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(from_unixtime(`date`) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)),
       SUM(from_unixtime(`date`) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
FROM `login_log`;
```

MySQL treats boolean values as integers, with `1` being "true" and `0` being "false".  So, using `sum()` you can count the number of matching values.  (In other databases, you would do something similar using `case`.)

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's pretty tough to understand what you ask:

If you want them in the same column use `OR`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from 'login_log' where from_unixtime('date') >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) OR from_unixtime('date') >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ;
```

If you don't want duplicate answers: use `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

Use the where condition with one month internal and add the same where condition with one week internal as a Boolean column return.

I mean

```
Select count (*) all_in_month, (from_unixtime(`date`) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) as in_week from `login_log` where from_unixtime(`date`) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 a MONTH) GROUP BY in_week;
```

P.s. haven't tested but afaik it should work