# How to merge these two queries into a comparison query

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have these two queries:

```
"SELECT company.id, company.name, 
        contact.firstname, contact.lastname, 
        contact.email, contact.id AS contactid
   from ecampaign_lookup
   LEFT JOIN company ON ecampaign_lookup.companyid=company.id 
   LEFT JOIN contact ON ecampaign_lookup.contactid=contact.id
  WHERE ecampaign_lookup.campaignid=".$tid;
```

And:

```
"SELECT company.id, company.name, 
         contact.firstname, contact.lastname, 
         contact.email, contact.id AS contactid
   from ecampaign_lookup
   LEFT JOIN company ON ecampaign_lookup.companyid=company.id 
   LEFT JOIN contact ON contact.companyid=company.id
  WHERE ecampaign_lookup.campaignid=".$tid." 
    AND contact.defaultcontact=1";
```

The difference is the first query returns contacts from the 'ecampaign_lookup' table and the second returns contacts from the 'company' table. The second query also has the requirement of only selecting contacts where 'contact.defaultcontact=1' as there are many contacts per company but only one contact per ecampaign_lookup.

At the moment I'm running these two queries separately and then using a for loop to compare the results, which will be prone to errors if one query returns less or more than the other:

```
        for ($x=0;$x<count($query1_result);$x++){
                if ($query1_result[$x]['contactid']!=$query2_result[$x]['contactid']){
                     echo $query1_result[$x]['firstname']." has been replaced by ".
                     $query2_result[$x]['firstname'];   
                }
        }
```

How can I merge the two queries together to compare ecampaign_lookup.contactid with the contact.id in the second query and only return results where the two don't match?

Comment: I've asked similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/25106708/2244570 a bit different, but you can get the point and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after much trial and error I found a solution using a subquery:

```
 SELECT company.id,
       company.NAME,
       contact.firstname,
       contact.lastname,
       contact.email,
       contact.id AS contactid
FROM   ecampaign_lookup
       LEFT JOIN company
              ON ecampaign_lookup.companyid = company.id
       LEFT JOIN contact
              ON contact.companyid = company.id
WHERE  ecampaign_lookup.campaignid = :tid
       AND contact.defaultcontact = 1
       AND contact.id NOT IN (SELECT contact.id AS contactid
                              FROM   ecampaign_lookup
                                     LEFT JOIN company
                                            ON
                                     ecampaign_lookup.companyid = company.id
                                     LEFT JOIN contact
                                            ON
                                     ecampaign_lookup.contactid = contact.id
                                     WHERE  ecampaign_lookup.campaignid = :tid)
```

Answer (score 4):

To compare two query, [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) and the `HAVING` clause it the key.

This example should work and return only duplicate rows.

```sql
SELECT id, name, firstname, lastname, email, contactid
FROM
(
  SELECT company.id, company.name, 
     contact.firstname, contact.lastname, 
     contact.email, contact.id AS contactid
  FROM ecampaign_lookup
  LEFT JOIN company ON ecampaign_lookup.companyid=company.id 
  LEFT JOIN contact ON ecampaign_lookup.contactid=contact.id
  WHERE ecampaign_lookup.campaignid=:tid

  UNION ALL

  SELECT cp2.id, cp2.name, 
     ct2.firstname, ct2.lastname, 
     ct2.email, ct2.id AS contactid
  FROM ecampaign_lookup ecl2
  LEFT JOIN company cp2 ON ecl2.companyid=cp2.id 
  LEFT JOIN contact ct2 ON ct2.companyid=cp2.id
  WHERE ecl2.campaignid=:tid AND ct2.defaultcontact=1
)
GROUP BY id, name, firstname, lastname, email, contactid
HAVING count(*) >= 1
```

Comment: There needs to be an alias after the ), but even with that it returns all rows