# How to get multiple counts and sum with one SQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have 3-5 mysql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM aso_repairs WHERE repairs_date_end = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND repairs_supply_repair_users_id = ''
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM aso_repairs WHERE repairs_date_end != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND repairs_supply_repair_users_id != '0'
SELECT repairs_id FROM aso_repairs ORDER BY repairs_id DESC
```

How I can make this in one query?

Like:

```
 (FIRST COUNT) AS count1, (SECOND COUNT) AS count2, (LAST QUERY) AS count3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine 2 MySQL queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106607/combine-2-mysql-queries)

Answer (score 0):

use union and make every select with 3 columns  :

```
select sum(count1),sum(count2),sum(count3)
from 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'count1',0 as 'count2' ,0 as 'count3' FROM aso_repairs WHERE repairs_date_end = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND repairs_supply_repair_users_id = ''
union
SELECT 0 as 'count1',COUNT(*) as 'count2',0 as 'count3' FROM aso_repairs WHERE repairs_date_end != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND repairs_supply_repair_users_id != '0'
union
SELECT 0 as 'count1' ,0 as 'count2',repairs_id as 'count3' FROM aso_repairs ORDER BY repairs_id DESC
)RS_count
```

Comment: you are counting on the same table with different conditions  i edited my answer  now it should work